# Check size and names via scp

Tags: linux, sftp, scp

I used this cmd

```
scp -r Demo/ user@host:/Demo/
```

How can I set scp[or fstp] to check size and name of all files and folder?
and just transfers new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCP is not smart enough to do that. The functionality you are looking for is a core feature of [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Comment: can I install rsync just on my server? or I have to install to my server and the backup host?

Comment: @Mohammad rsync has be on both ends, however it is a very very common linux tool so is likely to already be present.

Comment: unfortunatly I can only use it on one side! my backup server is from Hetzner. here is my backup host : [link](https://www.hetzner.de/us/hosting/storagebox/bx30)

Comment: @Mohammad ah in that case you could mount it as a CIFS drive and use rync, which would not require it to be present on the remote host.